# What is the metadata attribute of Spark's StructField object

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am currently trying to find the purpose of the `metadata` attribute of the StructField object in Spark.

I have searched the official documentation https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=structfield#pyspark.sql.types.StructField

But I still do not understand the purpose of this variable. I mean can I, for example, set an option of primary key thanks to `metadata`? If yes, what should this dict look like?

Or more generally, what is its purpose and how to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure either, but I know you can put documentation strings in there. And then you can do all your selects, and as long as you keep copying the column (no expressions) the metadata can be pulled out unchanged. This is useful for making automated documentation on my computed tables.